# Are Express Validator and Express Mutually Exclusive or Dependent Packages

Tags: javascript, express

What should I use for validate the incoming request
express-validator or express.json parser that is shipped with it and does express-validator does the same thing as they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v4.16.0 you no longer need to use `body-parser`, instead you can use `express.json()`. Once you have the request body you can use `express-validator` to validate the input.

[Code examples available here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

**Edit**

To access the request body you have two options:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // Option A: middleware bodyParser
app.use(express.json()) // Option B: in-built method
```

**Neither** of these options **provide validation** of the body, **only access** to it. To validate a request body you must add middleware such as `express-validator`

```js
app.use(expressValidator())
```

Comment: yup i think so , and i'll improve the way i ask with in the next day howeverthank you for answer my question and the point here should i use them together as i know express.json parse the request and express-validator does it do same thing or No

Comment: @Adam with the additional information are you now clear on the differences between the two packages?

Comment: yup i do thanx man for this

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted and reformat your question to better reflect the question you were asking. The title could be: "Are Express Validator and Express Mutually Exclusive or Dependent Packages" or "Can Express Handle Validation Without An Additional Package". I will leave you to reformat the body and will provide any feedback as necessary. It is important that you learn how to effectively ask questions on this site as it is the only way you can reliably get your questions answered going forward.